# What is the correct way to use a value converter to assign a selector(drawable) in mvvm cross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a View

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/sel_fragfinder_toolbar_selection_selected"
            local:MvxBind="Drawable DiscoverYourScent;Converter=ButtonState"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Discover your scent" />
```

**Where I have bind property for converter:**

```
public class ButtonStateValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool,int>
    {
        protected override int Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value) {
              return  Resource.Drawable.sel_fragfinder_toolbar_selection_selected;
            }else{
              return  Resource.Drawable.sel_fragfinder_toolbar_selection_not_selected;
            }
        }
    }
```

**In View Model, I am setting**

```
private bool _discoverYourScent;
        public bool DiscoverYourScent
        {
            get { return _discoverYourScent; }
            set { _discoverYourScent = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => DiscoverYourScent); }
        }
```

**And I am setting `DiscoverYourScent = true;`**

---

### *Currently It is not setting .... What is the correct way to use a value converter to assign a selector(drawable) in mvvm cross*

Comment: Instead of trying to bind to `Drawable`, have you tried binding to `Selected` instead? Then Android will choose the appropriate state selector. BTW: Mvx currently only supports binding to Drawable from views dervived from `ImageVIew`. See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L128-L130

Answer (score 0):

Your binding expression is:

```
Drawable DiscoverYourScent;Converter=ButtonState
```

The problem here is that you have a `;` semicolon between your Source Target assignment and your Converter statements.

It needs to be a `,` comma.

```
Drawable DiscoverYourScent, Converter=ButtonState
```

Alternatively you can also write:

```
Drawable ButtonState(DiscoverYourScent)
```

You should see your `ValueConverter` be hit now if the rest of the binding is correct. I believe you want to bind to `Background` as Source and not `Drawable`. Latter does not seem to be a public property on `Button`.

As Kiliman points out in the comments to the OP, you could also try your luck setting the `Selected` property instead, and don't change your Drawable. Just make sure the Drawable you use has the correct states.